# Why does adding a <service> node for my http/https WCF Data service result in a Resource Not Found when I 'open' it in a browser?

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have an azure web role that hosts a WCF Data Service (System.Data 5.6.1). I configured the web role for 2 endpoints http and https. I was able to deploy to azure and I was able to do a simple test by opening a browser to both endpoints e.g., http://XX.XX.XXX.213:8082/MyDataService.svc/MyItems() and
https://XX.XX.XXX.213:8083/MyDataService.svc/MyItems() and get the feeds back.

I knew some of my future queries to this web service might exceed the default limits of the webHttpBinding used by a WCF Data Service so I added a very basic  configuration in the  of my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
    <service name="BNN.Nuform.Demog.WebService.DemogDataService">
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="msgSize" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="msgSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Over the http endpoint everything works fine.

But over the https endpoint  it does not work at all. If I open a browser and try anything I always get back RESOURCE NOT FOUND.
What is happening?

Comment: Have you tried adding binding with transport security?   You'll need to add another endpoint or that, though, I believe.

Comment: I added <security mode="Transport"/> under the webHttpBinding/binding section and added a service behavior where httpGetEnabled and httpsGetEnabled are both set to true; After doing that, the https endpoint works BUT NOW THE HTTP ENDPOINT STOPPED WORKING. It looks like I can't get them both working, it's either one or the other???????

Comment: You need two bindings - one for https (with transport security) and one for http (without transport security).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a binding configuration created for each of the different ways you wish to access your service.

In the case where you want to be able to access the service either via HTTP or HTTPS you could create 2 separate binding configurations matched with 2 service endpoints.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
        <service name="BNN.Nuform.Demog.WebService.DemogDataService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="msgSize" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="msgSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
            </binding>
            <binding name="secureBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The example above the second endpoint defined within the Service section allows you to reference the secure binding configuration.